# AutoIt v3 function with optional/default parameter

Tags: function, parameters, autoit

I am trying to call a function declared like this:

```
Func doCall($indexNumber = "1")
MsgBox(0, "Test", $indexNumber) 
EndFunc
```

but I get an error about the `$indexNumber` variable not being declared prior to use. I want to be able to call `doCall()` without the `$indexNumber` parameter also, the `MsgBox` should display `1`, right ?

Can this be done ? Or any other solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put this into a file and ran it successfully...it displayed a message box with a 1.

```
doCall()

Func doCall($indexNumber = "1")
  MsgBox(0, "Test", $indexNumber) 
EndFunc
```

### EDIT

Try adding a handler function:

```
Func doCallHandler()
  doCall()
EndFunc
```

Then, do this:

```
GUICtrlSetOnEvent($Button1, "doCallHandler")
```

Comment: I am calling my function from a button like this `GUICtrlSetOnEvent($Button1,"doCall")` . Does this makes any difference ? I am also able to test this in separate project file but once I get in my script it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare your variable, you shouldn't have any issues. Add this near the top of your script (before `$indexNumber` is referenced):

```
Global $indexNumber
```

---

**EDIT**

I'm not sure why the default value isn't picked up when using `GUICtrlSetOnEvent`. As a work-around, try modifying your function like this:

```
Func doCall($indexNumber = "1")
    If $indexNumber = '' Then $indexNumber = '1'
    MsgBox(0, "Test", $indexNumber)
EndFunc
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Well, it got rid of the error, but the message box was empty.

Comment: @aphoria - I was able to reproduce the issue. Not sure why it won't pick up the default value when using `GUICtrlSetOnEvent`. I edited my answer with something else to try.

Comment: I believe Event methods cannot have parameters.

Comment: I know you can't pass a parameter, but I would've thought that any optional parameters in the function definition would still get their default values.

Comment: Thanks but the update still won't work as AutoIt crashes at this line first `Func doCall($indexNumber = "1")`, it does not reach the $indexNumber value check.